# CookieManager and CookieSyncManager not syncing cookies to webview in ICS (works on all previous API levels)

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

**Background:**

I'm acquireing cookies through my app and use them internally by making requests to http. Users can switch to webview any given time, in which case I sync/inject cookies to [webView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Code for synchronizing cookies to webview using [CookieSyncManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html):

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(a);
CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
cm.setCookie(domain, cookieName + "=" + cookieValue);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

This works on **all** API levels **except** API 15+ (Android 4.0, Ice Cream Sandwich). The [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) API is not deprecated.

What is causing this problem and are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the Apache DefaultHttpClient to do this work for you, I don't think it been changed in Ice Cream Sandwich.

I found this [sample](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html), but there is lots more in here

Comment: This could actually work... Overriding the `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to use the `Apache DedfaultHttpClient` to acquire webpage using cookies and inject the HTML into webview with `webView.loadData` (meaning, you handle all the logic and webview is used only for displaying/rendering HTML)

Comment: @Beuj found another one

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem recently which I found was my mistake. The problem was the way I set the domain (but it worked till API 15). Try to prefix the domain with the dot: ".company.com" instead of "company.com".

Comment: This worked, but I found that it caused the same problem in reverse - it'd work in ICS, and not pre-ICS. I had to do a quick if-else to use ".domain.com" if the app was running on Ice Cream Sandwich, and "domain.com" if not. Strange.

Comment: After tried lot of various ways, Finally Worked for me by just adding a dot before domain cookieManager.setCookie("."+domain, cookie);

Comment: What does the domain variable contain?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't injecting cookie from the client, but i found ICS
cookie weren't saving.

One work around is 
to use the local storage instead of cookies. You don't need a cookie sync manager.
this works on ics and v2+  android.

In my case I didn't have a domain , so the above didn't seem relevant
- I was using a local html file in the asset folder of the app.

this works on ics and v2 android

enjoy

java

```
// java
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);   // localStorage


// e.g., if your package is www.myapp.whatever;
webSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/www.myapp.whatever/databases/");
```

html

```
// javascript

function createCookie(name,value,days,path) {
    localStorage.setItem(name,value);
}

function readCookie(name) {
    return localStorage.getItem(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer : [In ICs, can`t get cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811848/in-ics-cant-get-cookie/13594198#13594198)

Its the domain which is causing the issue.

for all version after 15+ you have to you have to use **.**domain.com , instead of domain.com.