# In ICs, can`t get cookie

Tags: android, cookies, session-cookies, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, httpurlconnection

cookie return always null...

In android 2.x this works well, but 4.0.4 ICS not works

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
CookieManager cookie = CookieManager.getInstance();

            if(cookie.getCookie(mContext.getString(R.string.host_url))!=null){
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.getCookie(mContext.getString(R.string.host_url)));
                Log.d("tag", "cookie get " +  cookie.getCookie(mContext.getString(R.string.host_url)));
            }
```

in this code  cookie.getCookie() return always null...

*using this code in HttpUrlConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a dot in front of the url. For example if it was "domain.com" change it to ".domain.com"
But still it wont work for previous versions. So check for the version and do if else. All version before 4.0 works good for "domain.com"